# How to convert Querytable to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-store-apps

newbie in SQlite

I dont managed to convert a QueryTable # SQlite to an ObservableCollection in C # (WindowsStore).

I mean, I created a class called person, which inherits from BindableBase. (model):

```
class Person : BindableBase
{
    private int _id;
    public int id { get { return _id; } set {SetProperty(ref _id, value);} }

    private string _Name;
    public string Name { get { return _Name; } set {SetProperty(ref _Name, value);} }

    private string _LastName;
    public string LastName { get {return _LastName;} set {SetProperty(ref _LastName, value);} }

    private double _Celphone;
    public double Celphone { get {return _Celphone;} set {SetProperty(ref _Celphone, value);} }

}
```

I created another class called PersonCollection (model)

```
class PersonCollection: ObservableCollection<Person>
{
}
```

ok, now, when I try to fill the collection with the data of the table (ViewModel), I can not do the cast of tablequery to ObservableCollection. How to fix this.

My ViewModel Class:

```
class PersonVM: BindableBase
{       
    private PersonCollection _PersonList;
    public PersonCollection PersonList {get {return _PersonList;} 
                                        set {SetProperty(ref _PersonList, value);} }



    public async Task<bool> GetPersons()
    {
        try
        {
            var dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.db3");
            using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
            {
                var listadepersonas = from x in db.Table<Person>() select x;
                foreach (var persona in listadepersonas)
                {
                    PersonList.Add(new Person() 
                    { id = persona.id, Name = persona.LastName, 
                      LastName = persona.LastName, Celphone = persona.Celphone });
                }
                db.Dispose();
                db.Close();
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string sErr = ex.Message;
            return false;
        }                           
}
```

and exception returns me: 
ex.Message = "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not initizalizing the `PersonList`, so `PersonList` is null. That's why you are getting `NullReferenceException`, `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

```
public async Task<bool> GetPersons()
{
    try
    {
        var dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.db3");

        //Initialize the PersonList, so PersonList won't be null.
        PersonList = new PersonCollection();
        using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
        {
            var listadepersonas = from x in db.Table<Person>() select x;
            foreach (var persona in listadepersonas)
            {
                PersonList.Add(new Person()
                {
                    id = persona.id,
                    Name = persona.LastName,
                    LastName = persona.LastName,
                    Celphone = persona.Celphone
                });
            }
            db.Dispose();
            db.Close();
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string sErr = ex.Message;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: thats happen when you dont rest and sleep!... thnks!